# PHP Zend Debugger configuration

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-debugger

Hi i am new to php, I currently learning php using eclipse. I know i have to install the zend debugger my php.ini store at c:windows i had added in these line:

```
[Zend]
zend_extension=c:/php/ext/ZendDebugger.dll
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
zend_debugger.connector_port=10013
```

but on command prompt i tried php -m it shown that i never install zend debugger. I not sure where goes wrong I check phpinfo also never show any zend information.

Comment: check php --ini  to see whether you've edited the correct php.ini file.

Comment: ya i check alot of time le 
[Zend] 
zend_extension=c:/php/ext/ZendDebugger.dll zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1 zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always zend_debugger.connector_port=10013

Comment: *(reference)* http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=962

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a browser go to:
http://localhost/?phpinfo=1

look for "Loaded Configuration File"
and take a note of the path

Now open a DOS prompt window (Start > Run > (type) cmd)
and at the command line type
c:\path\to\your\php\php.exe -r phpinfo(); |more
(press CTRL+C to break)

Again look for:
"Loaded Configuration File"
and take a note of this path.

It could be that you are using a different php.ini for your webserver and for the CLI version.

You will need to add the config changes to both php.ini files or put the config in a file called zend.ini and place that in the folder that is mentioned in your phpinfo output under:
"Scan this dir for additional .ini files"

Answer (score 3):

I had lots of problems making the debugger work. Now I'm using the ZendServer CE which is free and the configuration is a lot easier.

Also I use Eclipse + PDT, downloaded from Zend Site.

This should work right out of the box. Why not using ZendServer? you get everything you want in a package.

Comment: Agreed with Alex.  Installing Zend Server CE http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/index is by far the easiest road to go.

Comment: Excuse me for the lame question, is Zend server a web server? does it replace Apache or it works on Apache?

Comment: Zend server includes an Apache server. So, its an easy installation of PHP + Zend Debugger + Apache with an interface. There are others, like MAMP or whatever but I've been using ZendServer Community Edition (=free) for a while and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same thing when I was using thread-safe PHP on Windows.

Up to date versions of the Zend Debugger no longer support running in thread-safe flavors of PHP on Windows. Switching to a non-thread-safe (a.k.a nts) flavor of PHP fixed this issue for me.

See here: http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=1918#p13729